# What exactly is a delegate?

Tags: performance, c#-4.0, delegates, action

I use delegates (Actions, WaitCallbacks, Funcs) quite often but I am trying to get a better understanding of exactly 'what' they are.

I have a fairly good understanding of objects vs reference types, etc. and where they are stored on the heap vs. the stack?

Basically - I'm trying to understanding using delegates from a performance standpoint. Does anyone have any links to resources or perhaps a good explanation?

Also - what exactly 'are' events?  How do they relate to delegates?  Are they basically just a list of delegates that gets iterated over?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone distill into proper English what a delegate is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541683/can-someone-distill-into-proper-english-what-a-delegate-is)

Comment: Just so you know, the stack vs heap thing is an implementation detail -- and a misleadingly oversimplified one, at that.  The heap can store anything the stack can, else you couldn't have an `int` field inside your object.

Comment: `ildasm` will answer all your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything that was said so far is correct. Here is how it works under the covers: A delegate has two fields: A pointer to executable code and a field of type object that represents the this parameter (you can take a delegate to an instance method).

When you invoke this delegate the CPU will fetch the pointer to the code into a register and then "call" this pointer. Call instructions do not need to use constant values. The CPU can jump to a variable location in memory.

Events are just delegates plus two wrapper methods to attach a new delegate or to remove an existing one. The confusing part is that delegates have a 3rd field I left out: A delegate! delegates form a linked list. This is called a MulticastDelegate and it is an abomination. When you invoke a delegate it can cause *multiple* methods with the same signature to be invoked. This is how events work. An event is a single field of a delegate type.

Now forget about multicast delegates because they are not relevant in practice.

Comment: So when you say that the 'CPU can jump to a variable location in memory' are you talking about the stack or the heap?  And how do events fit into all of this?

Comment: I added a paragraph for events. I did not understand what you meant by "stack or heap". What has this to do with delegates? The CPU does not jump to data (on the stack or heap). It jumps into Jitted code which lies on a runtime-internal code-heap. Code is just bytes in memory.

Comment: Maybe you misread "variable location". This has nothing to do with a variable. The location itself is variable, it cannot be determined statically. It is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are data structures that represent functions - a return type and the arguments (types and numbers). Any method that matches the delegate return type and signature can be assigned to such a delegate.

In terms of performance - this is an extra layer of abstraction, but a small one. This is not something you are likely to notice.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates can be two types, from what I understand:

- "instance-bound method pointers", which means that the delegate contains the object instance of the subscribing object, and the method in the object's class to invoke. If I have MyClass.Handler(), and I create five instances of MyClass, and create 5 delegates for each instance, pointing to the Handler() method, then each delegate will have the same method pointer, but a different object instance.
- Static method pointers, eg, delegates to static methods, in which case no object context is needed.

Events are MulticastDelegate objects, you can even inspect them to see who is subscribing to the events. Using reflection you can audit subscribers to your events.

Answer (score 0):

A delegate is a C# language element that allows you to reference a method. If you were a C or C++ programmer, this would sound familiar because a delegate is basically a **function pointer**. However, developers who have used other languages are probably wondering, "Why do I need a reference to a method?". The answer boils down to giving you maximum flexibility to implement any functionality you want at runtime.