# C# Benefit of Delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone distill into proper English what a delegate is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541683/can-someone-distill-into-proper-english-what-a-delegate-is)

I've been trying to work out the benefit of using delegates, however I still haven't found anything on the internet that explains it properly.

Why is the code below (which uses delegates) better than the following piece of code?

```
delegate int DiscountDelegate();

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    DiscountDelegate discount = null;
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
    {
      discount = new DiscountDelegate(calc.Morning);
    }
    else if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 20)
    {
      discount = new DiscountDelegate(calc.Afternoon);
    }
    else
    {
      discount = new DiscountDelegate(calc.Night);
    }
    new ShoppingCart().Process(discount);
  }
}

class Calculator
{
  public int Morning()
  {
    return 5;
  }
  public int Afternoon()
  {
    return 10;
  }
  public int Night()
  {
    return 15;
  }
}

class ShoppingCart
{
  public void Process(DiscountDelegate discount)
  {
    int magicDiscount = discount();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Compared to:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    int discount;
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
    {
      discount = calc.Morning();
    }
    else if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 20)
    {
      discount = calc.Afternoon();
    }
    else
    {
      discount = calc.Night();
    }
    new ShoppingCart().Process(discount);
  }
}

class Calculator
{
  public int Morning()
  {
    return 5;
  }
  public int Afternoon()
  {
    return 10;
  }
  public int Night()
  {
    return 15;
  }
}

class ShoppingCart
{
  public void Process(int discount)
  {
    int magicDiscount = discount;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: In this code, no advantages at all. Use a delegate when you need to pass *behavior* around. Here you're only passing values.

Comment: In that example you don't have any benefit  from the Delegates.The Main use of Delegates is in Events in C#.

Comment: Recommended link : http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html

Comment: if there was some more functionality that was added to the program, then would there be some benefit in using delegates? if so, can you extend my code to provide an example?

Comment: Delegates are function pointers.  In your case, you might not immediately see the advantages, but they are used for thread-safe situations like callback functions or windows events. When you register a windows eventhandler, you are registering a delegate to a stack. When the event is triggered, it invokes the events from the stack. Study the windows event handlers, the MVC design patterns, or linq (e.g. the predicate delegate).  It is so powerful that they have 3 ways to experess a delegate.